# Checking for valid OTP using session variable

Tags: php, forms, session, session-variables

I am trying to send an SMS OTP and retrieve it from user to verify the user.
My SMS script is working fine, but I am not able to store in session variable and check whether it is valid OTP for that particular user.

**index.php**

```
<?php
$otp1 = '';
for($i=4;$i>0;$i--)
{
    $otp1 = $otp1.chr(rand(48,57));
}    

// SMS script here (working fine)

?>

<form action="process.php" method="post">
Enter OTP: <br>
<input type="number" name="otp2" >
<br>
<? php
session_start();
$_SESSION['otpnuser'] = 1;
$_SESSION['secretpassword'] = $otp1;
$_SESSION["otp2"] = $otp1;


?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_POST["otp2"] == $_SESSION["otp2"])
{
    $_SESSION['otpuser'] = 1;
    header("Refresh: 2; URL=success.php");
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['otpuser'] = 0;
    header("Refresh: 2; URL=fail.php");  
}
?>
```

It is always redirecting me to the **fail.php** page even if the OTP is correct.

Comment: where are you declaring `$_SESSION["otp2"]` in your index.php ?

Comment: $_SESSION["otp2"] = $otp1;  should be declared in the index.php page??

Answer (score 0):

`if($_POST["otp2"] == $_SESSION["otp2"])` always going to be false, because u haven't declared/assign any value `otp2`

on your `index.php`

`session_start();`

`$_SESSION['otpnuser'] = 1;`

`$_SESSION['secretpassword'] = $otp1;`

**`$_SESSION["otp2"] = "SOME VALUE";`**

`

Comment: I did this `$_SESSION["otp2"] = $otp1;` in the index.php, to check if the post value (otp2) and otp1 is same.
But still it is not working.
(Code Updated)

Comment: replace ` $_SESSION['otp2']` with `$_SESSION['secretpassword'] ` in your process.php

Comment: I am getting this now
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''] == $_SESSION['' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']' in C:\xamppnew\htdocs\otp\process.php on line 3`